# Unable to find docusign models in typescript code

Tags: typescript, docusignapi, package.json

I am doing this:

```
import * as docusign from 'docusign-esign';
```

but when I call

```
let signer1Tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
```

I get this error. It is one of several like this:

error TS2339: Property 'Tabs' does not exist on type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/@types/docusign-esign/index")'.

218     let signer1Tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({

In `package.json` I include these:

```
"@types/docusign-esign": "^5.5.1",
"docusign-admin": "1.0.0-beta",
"docusign-click": "^1.0.0",
"docusign-esign": "^5.12.0",
"docusign-monitor": "^1.0.0",
"docusign-rooms": "^1.1.0",
```

And the files do exist:

```
find node_modules/docusign-esign -name Tabs.js   
node_modules/docusign-esign/src/model/Tabs.js
```

Not certain why they are not being found.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to import the specific classes you're using instead of *?

Here's what I'm using:

`import { Tabs } from 'docusign-esign';`